# Is it firstChild that I need?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, customization

I am changing the theme of a wordPress site.

Javascript that works on the old site, does not work on the new (test) site because the structure of the dom is different.
The old HTML dom just included:

```
<img src="http://somewhereRemoved.jpg" class="header-img" />
```

So the old script to change the img was:

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName("header-img");    // there IS only ONE! in this class
img[0].src = "http://somewhereRemoved.gif"+"?a="+Math.random();
```

The new dom/customization only allows me to set Class & Id for the **parent** element, not the image:

```
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large v12-OurHeroImage" id="V12-OurHeroImage">
   <img decoding="async" width="1024" height="341" src="http://somewhereRemoved-1024x341.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-1045" srcset="http://somewhereRemoved-1024x341.jpg 1024w, http:/somewhereRemoved-600x200.jpg 600w, http://somewhereRemoved-300x100.jpg 300w, http://somewhereRemoved-768x256.jpg 768w, http://somewhereRemoved-240x80.jpg 240w, http://somewhereRemoved.jpg 1200w" sizes="(max-width: 1024px) 100vw, 1024px" />
</figure>
```

Initially, I tried:

```
var img = document.getElementById('wp-image-1045');    // I hope there is only ONE instance?
img[0].src = "http://somewhereRemoved.gif"+"?a="+Math.random();
```

But got the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'src')

1. Why the error?

But if class "wp-image-1045" cannot be guaranteed to be unique, would I be better referencing the parent element (for which I can set the class & id):

```
let content = document.getElementsByClassName('v12-OurHeroImage');
let firstChild = content.firstChild.nodeName;
img[0].src = "http://somewhereRemoved.gif"+"?a="+Math.random();
```

But I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'nodeName')

2. Where have I gone wrong?

*nb. real file references have been replaced with "somewhereRemoved" to protect the innocent*

---------Additional info---------

Even when using @This Guy 's corrections, I'm still having problems saying e.g. scr is undefined.  The complete html is given below.  Is the new problem  because of src & srcset?

```
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large v12-OurHeroImage" id="V12-OurHeroImage">
   <img decoding="async" width="1024" height="341" src="http://somewhereRemoved-1024x341.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-1045" srcset="http://somewhereRemoved-1024x341.jpg 1024w, http://somewhereRemoved-600x200.jpg 600w, http://somewhereRemoved-300x100.jpg 300w, http://somewhereRemoved-768x256.jpg 768w, http://somewhereRemoved-240x80.jpg 240w, http://somewhereRemoved.jpg 1200w" sizes="(max-width: 1024px) 100vw, 1024px">
</figure>



var img = document.getElementsByClassName("wp-image-1045");    // there is only ONE????
    img[0].src = "http://somewhereRemoved.gif"+"?a="+Math.random();
```

Gives the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'src')

Comment: 1. the error is because you get a single element not an array. so just use img.src, not img[0].src

Comment: just use content.firstChild, should return the element. then use firstChild.src = "http://protectTheInnocent.now/..."

Comment: have you much experience using the dev tools and console (F12)? I find them very helpful, I'm sure there are better approaches too! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console you can test out collectors and see what returns, so that you can see if you need to treat things as arrays or objects

Comment: @This Guy  Thanks, but have I misunderstood?  
 'code'  var img = document.getElementsByClassName('wp-image-1045'); 
img.scr = "somewhereRemoved.gif"+"?a="+Math.random();      Doesnt error, but doesn't refresh the image either.

Comment: and:  'code' let content = document.getElementById('v12-OurHeroImage');
let firstChild = content.firstChild.nodeName;
firstChild.src = somewhereRemoved.gif"+"?a="+Math.random();     ... gives error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'firstChild')

Comment: I've added some 'additional info' to the original post with more of the complete html.

Comment: Cool. well, a very helpful tool is to use the console and you can actually select elements, then reference them using $0 so, select an element and just type $0 you will get the object